# Initializer List and Constructor function call order

Tags: c#

What is the call order for initialization list vs constructor function?

```
public class MyClass {

    public int MyIntegerValue { set; get; }

    public MyClass() {
        if(MyIntegerValue = 5) {
           DoA();
        } else {
           DoB();
        }
    }
}
```

Given the previous code, if I call `new MyClass() { MyIntegerValue = 5 }` will `DoA()` or `DoB()` be executed?

in case `DoB()` is executed, is there a way for it to call `DoA()` without passing `MyIntegerValue` as a parameter to the constructor function?

Comment: Is `MyIntegerValue` a property of `MyClass`?  If so, could you add that to your code snippet?

Comment: Also, you can test this for yourself with a quick command-line app probably faster than you got the question written.

Comment: @adv12 Nevertheless this is an interesting question that people can learn from. I don't get people's urge to downvote. If you don't like the question, don't answer it.

Comment: What did you try? This seems like an easy one to figure out on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it will execute `DoB` because first constructor will be called and them MyIntegerValue will be assigned.

Your code is simply

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
mc.MyIntegerValue = 5;
```

However you can do

```
private int _MyIntegerValue = 5;

public int MyIntegerValue
{
    get { return _MyIntegerValue; }
    set { _MyIntegerValue = value; }
}
```

**OR**

```
public MyClass(int _myIntegerValue)
{
    MyIntegerValue = _myIntegerValue;
    if (MyIntegerValue == 5)
        DoA();
    else
        DoB();
}
```

and call like this

```
new MyClass(5);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var x = new MyClass() { MyIntegerValue = 5 };
```

is shorthand for

```
var x = new MyClass();
x.MyIntegerValue = 5;
```

There's nothing to it but syntactic sugar.

So the answer is that the constructor is called first.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor will run 1st, so `MyIntegerValues` will be zero when the class is initialised.

Also, you have a typo. It should be

```
 if (MyIntegerValue === 5)  // not '=' (assignment) but '==' (equality check)
```

Perhaps you want something like:

```
public class MyClass {

public int MyIntegerValue { get; private set; }

public MyClass(int v) {
    MyIntegerValue = v;
    if(MyIntegerValue == 5) {
       DoA();
    } else {
       DoB();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use short hand to initialize your class but behind the scene it still execute your constructor first then initialize property.

So when your constructor get executed it's property does not set to value to 5 and so It will call DoB.

If you want to call DoA then you have to set property to Value 5 default. It has to something like this.

```
public class MyClass
    {

        private int _MyIntegerValue = 5;
        public int MyIntegerValue
        {
            get
            {
                return _MyIntegerValue;
            }
            set
            {
                _MyIntegerValue = value;
            }
        }

        public MyClass()
        {
            if (MyIntegerValue == 5)
            {
                DoA();
            }
            else
            {
                DoB();
            }
        }
}
```